# Are 777 permissions dangerous with fwrite?

Tags: php, forms, security, fwrite

I am in the process of testing my php form and logging all requests into a separate file. The purpose is to find out if the form is being used for spam and to hopefully eliminate it.

When using `fwrite()` to log the requests, is it dangerous or unnecessary to use 777 permissions? What is the alternative?

Comment: Execute is unnecessary (the final bit)

Answer (score 5):

You only need permission for the user the application is running as to be able to write to the file. It is also sometimes convenient for administrators to be able to read the file. Other than that, nobody needs access. Thus, `0640` are the most reasonable permissions for such a file.

In particular, nobody needs to *execute* the file, which is one of the bits set with `0777`. The execute bit is only needed for directories. (And executable programs, but that's not in play here.)

```
0640 = user/owner read/write, group read only, other no access
0777 = user/owner read/write/execute, group read/write/execute, other read/write/execute
```

The [`umask`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) is pretty useful for getting the permissions right. Instead of creating a file with explicit permission, you use `umask` to set a permissions template. Since directories need executable permissions and files do not, `umask` will mask permissions more sanely for the different types of files than setting them explicitly. For example, in your case:

```
umask(027); // Owner permissions unchanged, Group permissions mask 2, drop all other permissions
fopen('foo', 'w', 0777); // Creates file with *0640* permissions, because of mask
mkdir('bar', 0777); // Creates dir with *0750* permissions, because of mask
```

Comment: When I apply 640 permissions to the folder, I'm no longer able to view the form...

Comment: @user3216933 Files should be 0640, dirs should be 0750. The leading zero indicates the number is octal – if you leave off the leading zero it's a completely different value. Please see my updates and use `umask`.

Comment: I made all the files 0640 and the directories 0750. But I'm now getting a "forbidden" error, and no longer a 404.

Comment: @user3216933 What is giving you that error, under what circumstances?

Comment: I'm just viewing the index.php page (where the form is at) and I can no longer access it when the file permissions are at 0640.

Comment: @user3216933 Is the web server's user account the owner or group owner of the file? How did you set the permissions?

Comment: I right-clicked on the files in FileZilla and set the permissions that way. Not sure about the user account question.

Comment: @user3216933 your original question was about `fwrite`. Now you're asking about the webroot in general. I think that belongs in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

777 permission is set default by parent dir or php settings.
You can change it by `chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0640);`
[Check manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

And yes, this is ambitious and can be dangerous to have executable rights on files created by forms.

Good luck!

Comment: The `0777` permissions set by default are intended to be used with [`umask`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) to result in sane permissions. (Also note the leading zero is important for the value to be interpreted as octal.)